# LINQ and EF order by issue on specific table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm experiencing an odd issue: I'm using EF and already did a bunch of functioning linq query, like:

```
Dim dettaglio = From Dettagli_Contr In
                                    dbVulcano.Dettagli_Contr.Where(Function(d) d.RfCliente = richiesta.RFCliente And d.Scadenza > Date.Today)
                        Order By Dettagli_Contr.Scadenza
```

Now I want to do a similar query on a different table, but I can't, VS doesn't recognize the table and fails the Order By statement. This should be the query:

```
Dim statr = From StatoRic In
                                 dbVulcano.StatoRic.Where(Function(s) s.RFRic = rfRic)
                    From Stati In
                                 dbVulcano.Stati.Where(Function(t) t.IDStato = StatoRic.RFStato).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    Select StatoRic.RFStato, Stati.Descr, StatoRic.Data, StatoRic.Note
                    Order By StatoRic.Data Ascending, Stati.idstato
```

When it comes to Order By clause: in the first query VS recognize the keyword Dettagli_Contr as a table of dbVulcano and populate a dropdown with fields name like the one I used: Scadenza. In the second query VS recognize StatoRic as class and don't show me the list of fields. Also give me the error "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"
On what can this depends on? Something on the db table? Thank you

Comment: You have to switch the positions of  `Select` and `Order By` in the query. So like `From ..... Order By StatoRic.Data Ascending, Stati.idstato Select StatoRic.RFStato, Stati.Descr, StatoRic.Data, StatoRic.Note`. Linq is not like Sql in this manner, the select always comes last.

Comment: So simple! Thank you